# individual images as navigation design TwentyTen

Tags: menus, css, navigation, theme-twenty-ten

I can't figure out a solution for changing the black bar in Twenty Ten to individual background images behind each link. Using an image I created in Photoshop I have tried changing a few things in the CSS file but probably not the right changes.

Do I need to edit the functions file too?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the black bar of header navigation of WP TwentyTen theme by changing the background property of access id but when changing it try to make new rule more specific as following :

```
body #access{           
       background: none; // Add here image or color whatever you want
}
```

To apply individual background images behind each link, add background property to #access li element as shown below :

```
body #access li{           
       background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat;; // Add here appropriate image path
}
```

Comment: It works but the problem I have is my navigation text links are of different lengths so I created the image wide enough to accommodate all sizes except after implementing your solution the image behind each link looks squashed and distorted. I have included a screenshot for explanation purposes.
http://i46.tinypic.com/2nqehb4.png

Comment: What is your expected output? display the screenshot?

Comment: the image behind each link in the navigation should look like this (with the ability to resize each image individually) which I created in Photoshop http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=a31ngp&s=6 but from the screenshot I posted in my first reply as you can see it doesn't look how it should do.

Comment: Instead of image you can achieve same effect using background color and border radius css property. If you wan to use image then split it in three images right corner, left corner & middle image and apply it to the right and left to the list item & repeat middle image horizontally.

Comment: I would prefer to use an image as it is more likely to work in all browsers. How would the left, middle and right image work for when WP user decides to create a new link in the navigation. Is this my only choice if I want to use image?